# How to build a dictionary from contents of a csv file in kdb?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a csv file with contents like below

```
source,address,table,tableName,sym,symSet
source_one,addr1:port1:id1:pass1,table_one,tableName1,syms_one,SYM1 SYM2 SYM3
source_two,addr2:port2:id2:pass2,table_two,tableName2,syms_two,SYM21 SYM22 SYM23
```

My code to load a csv into a table is as below

```
table:("******";enlist ",") 0: `sourceFileName.csv
```

I want to create a dictionary out of contents of 'table' in the below format

```
source_one|addr1:port1:id1:pass1
table_one|tableName1
syms_one|SYM1 SYM2 SYM3
source_two|addr2:port2:id2:pass2
table_two|tableName2
syms_two|SYM21 SYM22 SYM23
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the table defined above you could make use of `value` to extract the data from the table without column headers:

```
q)value each table
"source_one" "addr1:port1:id1:pass1" "table_one" "tableName1" "syms_one" "SYM1 SYM2 SYM3"
"source_two" "addr2:port2:id2:pass2" "table_two" "tableName2" "syms_two" "SYM21 SYM22 SYM23"
```

From here you can `raze` the ouptut to give a single list which can then be `cut` into pairs (2):

```
q)2 cut raze value each table
"source_one" "addr1:port1:id1:pass1"
"table_one"  "tableName1"
"syms_one"   "SYM1 SYM2 SYM3"
...
```

Finally using `flip` puts it into a format that can be used to make a dictionary using `!`:

```
(!). flip 2 cut raze value each table
"source_one"| "addr1:port1:id1:pass1"
"table_one" | "tableName1"
"syms_one"  | "SYM1 SYM2 SYM3"
"source_two"| "addr2:port2:id2:pass2"
"table_two" | "tableName2"
"syms_two"  | "SYM21 SYM22 SYM23"
```

If the keys need to be symbols then you can make use of `@` apply to convert them before creating the dictionary:

```
(!). @[;0;`$]flip 2 cut raze value each table
```

A better approach may be to create the table without the use of `enlist` and dropping the column headers with `1_`, before making use of the same method to create the dictionary:

```
(!). flip raze cut[2]each 1_flip("******";",") 0: `:source.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed response! I tried doing it all once as suggested by you in the last line of your response(after removing column headers from the csv file) but I only get the last row of the file in dict format. Data from first row isn't included.

Comment: In the last line `1_` will remove the column headers, if you have already removed them then you can remove that step: ```(!). flip raze cut[2]each flip("******";",") 0: `:source.csv```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use 0: to directly Parse Key-Value Pairs however it would require a change to the way your text file is stored.

Need to drop the first line and add comma on the end of each line:

```
$ cat test.txt
source_one=addr1:port1:id1:pass1,table_one=tableName1,syms_one=SYM1 SYM2 SYM3,
source_two=addr2:port2:id2:pass2,table_two=tableName2,syms_two=SYM21 SYM22 SYM23,
```

If its easy to change the load then becomes one line:

```
q)(!). "S=,"0: raze  read0 `:test.txt
source_one| "addr1:port1:id1:pass1"
table_one | "tableName1"
syms_one  | "SYM1 SYM2 SYM3"
source_two| "addr2:port2:id2:pass2"
table_two | "tableName2"
syms_two  | "SYM21 SYM22 SYM23"
```

This has the advantage over loading to a table if the data is irregular, .e.g not ever line has source and table and syms.
If they did why not just have those as column names in a table?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be something like this:

```
q)(!) . flip raze 2 cut'1_flip("******";",")0:`:test.csv
"source_one"| "addr1:port1:id1:pass1"
"table_one" | "tableName1"
"syms_one"  | "SYM1 SYM2 SYM3"
"source_two"| "addr2:port2:id2:pass2"
"table_two" | "tableName2"
"syms_two"  | "SYM21 SYM22 SYM23"
```

(If you want the keys & values as symbols, replace the `*` in the `0:` params with `S`)

This works by reading the file in as lists of strings, flipping into the original rows, dropping the first (i.e. the headers), performing `2 cut` on each row to split into pairs, using `raze` to remove a level of nesting and then finally uses [dot apply](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/unclassified/#apply) to apply the `!` function (i.e. make a dictionary) to this flipped, so that the left arg to `!` is the keys and the right arg is the values.

Answer (score 1):

I would forego the table creation and do something like this:

```
q)(!). flip 2 cut raze ","vs/:1_read0`source.csv
"source_one"| "addr1:port1:id1:pass1"
"table_one" | "tableName1"
"syms_one"  | "SYM1 SYM2 SYM3"
"source_two"| "addr2:port2:id2:pass2"
"table_two" | "tableName2"
"syms_two"  | "SYM21 SYM22 SYM23"
```

Explanation.  From right to left, first, `1_read0` reads the source file as a list of lines and discards the first line.  Second, `","vs/:` cuts each line on `","` separators.  Third, `2 cut raze` flattens the list of lists and cuts it in pairs.  Fourth, `flip` transposes the list of pairs turning it into a pair of lists.  Last, `(!).` constructs a dictionary from a pair of lists containing keys and values.  Note that `(!).(x;y)` translates into `x!y`.